# How do i upload image to database from django form?

Tags: django, html, postgresql

I have tried this but did not work.

```
    class Agent(models.Model):
       first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
       last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
       email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
       cellPhone = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
       picture = models.ImageField(blank=False)



     class AgentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
        model = Agent
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','cellPhone','email', 'picture')


      <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%     csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

I select the file using the form button but it says "the field is required".

Comment: better if you can  add the full Model code, are you using the admin ? if not add the Form code too.

Comment: @sax i have added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it didn't work because you didn't mention the request.FILES in your views.py.

Whitout the request.FILES you can not receive the file uploaded.

`form = AgentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Answer (score 0):

If your user is uploading pictures, you need to have your MEDIA_ROOT settings on-point. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/files/)